# PHP even with session.use_trans_sid set to 1 and session.use_only_cookies I can not create a cookieless session

Tags: php, session, ubuntu, cookies, apache2

I have a login page, page A, that logs a user in and then re-directs them to a different page, page B. The problem is the other page, page B, does not see the session data, from page A, even with the above settings mentioned in the title set in apache2's php.ini file. Below are the relevant settings from my php.ini file.

```
 Directive                  Local Value   Master Value

 session.use_only_cookies   Off          Off
 session.use_trans_sid      1             1
```

I call `session_start();` at the top of my php scripts on both pages but still the other page does not see the session. When cookies are enabled in the browser the session does work but I cannot see the SID value. I am trying to code a totally cookie-less session in PHP though.

Thank-you for reading. Do not forget to breath. :D

Comment: Do you use a relative URL for the redirect?

Comment: I think so, check out my code `$home_url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . '/index.php';
    header('Location: ' . $home_url);`

Comment: No, your $home_url is absolute, not relative. The php docs say it won't append the SID to absolute URL's. Try taking out the http:// and host.

Comment: So the code is just `$home_url = dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . '/index.php';` ?

Comment: Actually yeah this worked... Although, I still do not see any value for SID and cookies have to be enabled. :D :/ 0_o

Answer (score 0):

To pull off cookie-less sessions, if you have to try as follows:

In a .php file you break from the PHP script with `?>` then add HTML code `<a href="index.php?<?php echo SID; ?>"home</a>`

Then if you need to code more PHP drop back into it with `<?php`

This is what I have:

```
   //lots of php scripting

     ?>
       <a href="index.php?<?php echo SID; ?>">Home</a>
        <!--html here -->   
    <?php
                 // more php scripting...:D
```

This allows cookie-less sessions - when the browser has cookies turned off. Now page B can see the value of SID since it is passed through the URL like a GET request. :D

Comment: In addition to tthat: PHP has it'S own URL rewriter that can handle href="" and action="" attributes in default config. but, as specified in the cfomments to the question, it doesn'T work for absolute links (as those may point to third party websites, which should never get the session ID).

another tihng one should keep in mind is security. a summary can be found here (including the comments there): http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.security.php

Comment: Thanks for the comments @Johannes H. :D I did not know this.  I am mainly using Sessions with Cookies because of this security hole.